# Both sides differentiation expression with integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a problem with derivation of some function. This is related to computing the Poincare Map of Logistic Population model with Periodic harvesting. This function is:

$\phi(t,x_0) = x_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(s,\phi(s,x_0)) ds $,

where $\phi(t,x_0)$ is a function: $\mathbb{R}  \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to differentiate  equation of this function both sides  with respect to $x_{0}$. In book from this equation comes from the result of this differentiation is:

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0} (t,x_0) = 1 + \int_0^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0} (s, x_0)ds$.

I can't understand expression under the integral. In this book it is explained that it is clear from **chain rule**.Could someone explain to me this transformation in easy way?
I will be grateful for your help
Best regards

Comment: what book is this from?

Comment: This is from:  Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems & An Introduction to Chaos. Morris W. Hirsch, Stephen Smale, Robert L. Devaney

Answer (score 3):

It really is just the chain rule, combined with differentiating under the integral sign. I'll ignore the parts you understand.

By Liebniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}\int_0^{t} f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) ds=\\
\int_0^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0} f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) ds
$$
Since your bounds do not depend on $x_0$ (otherwise you would have to include a correction function outside the integral). Then we just need to tackle the integrand, but that's just the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0} f(s, \phi(s,x_0))=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0}
$$
Since you have a composition of two functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer qbert. I'm still little confused, because when I'm trying to apply the chain rule I have expression such as: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_0} f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) = \frac{\partial }{\partial \phi(s,x_0) } f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x_0} \phi(s,x_0) $ Where of course s from point of view this partial derivative is constant isn't it? Could you explain me why in my expression first I have derivative respect by $\partial \phi(s,x_0)$ and then by $\partial x_0?$ In solution there are in both expressions $\partial x_0$ Why? Maybe important is here additional

Comment: (cont'd the part of Krzystof's comment chopped off while converting it to a comment, JL) information that differentiable function is solution of differential equation:

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (t,x_0) = f(t,\phi,x_0))$, where $\phi(0,x_0)=x(0).$